# Yii2: получить модели в контексте кастомного провайдера данных

Tags: ооп, yii2, наследование

Делаю кастомный дата-провайдер с поддержкой дерева.

Мне вполне достаточно функционала класса `ActiveDataProvider`, в который добавлены атрибут `$_tree` и геттер/сеттер:

```
private $_tree = null;

public function getTree()
{
    $this->prepare();

    return $this->_tree;
}

public function setTree($tree)
{
    $this->_tree = $tree;
}
```

плюс расширенный метод `prepare()`:

```
public function prepare($forcePrepare = false)
{
    parent::prepare($forcePrepare);

    if ($forcePrepare || $this->_tree === null)
        $this->_tree = $this->prepareTree($this->_models);
}
```

Загвоздка в том, что атрибут `$_models` определен как приватный в `BaseDataProvider`. Теоретически, я до него не могу добраться никак, кроме как используя `$this->getModels()`, фактически же, даже так я получить модели не могу (из-за возникающей рекурсии).

Есть решение в лоб: скопипастить `BaseDataProvider` и `ActiveDataProvider`, чтобы в первом изменить свойства атрибута `$_models` с `private` на `protected`. Оно мне не нравится.

Как все-таки минимальными усилиями, не создавая лишних классов, получить возможность в своем дата-провайдере достучаться до `$_models`?

Answer (score 1):

Перед тем как привести код, который может Вам помочь решить эту проблемы, хочу заметить, что вопрос, с которым Вы столкнулись - это верный сигнал о том, что где-то на предыдущем этапе Вы приняли ряд неверных архитектурных решений.

Вам необходимо нарушить инкапсуляцию предка, при этом Вы сильно зависите от его реализации. Настолько сильно, что, в принципе, готовы продублировать целых два класса, чтобы маленькую деталь этой самой реализации подправить.

*Наследование - это всегда очень сильная связь между классами*. В Вашем случае, я бы советовал *использовать композицию вместо наследования и имплементировать интерфейс `yii\data\DataProviderInterface`.*

Но, если Вы считаете, что это не подходит под Ваш случай, вот решение:

Вы можете достучаться к приватному свойству `$_models`, используя замыкания, указав новую область видимости (http://php.net/manual/ru/closure.bindto.php).

Рассмотрим тестовый пример:

```
abstract class TestGrandPa {

private $_models;

public function __construct($m)
{
    $this->_models = $m;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getModels()
{
    return $this->_models;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $models
 */
public function setModels($models)
{
    $this->_models = $models;
}

}

class TestPa extends TestGrandPa {

public function greet()
{
    echo 'Hello ' . $this->getModels();
}

protected function prepareGreet($m)
{
    return $m . '!';
}

}

class TestYouth extends TestPa {

public function prepare()
{
    $closure = function() {
        return $this->_models;
    };
    $binded = $closure->bindTo($this, 'TestGrandPa');
    $this->setModels($this->prepareGreet($binded()));
}

}

$y = new TestYouth('Denis');
$y->prepare();
echo $y->greet();
die();
```

Этот код выведет `Hello Denis!`.

Здесь я создаю замыкание, которое должно вернуть значение свойства объекта:

```
$closure = function() {
        return $this->_models;
};
```

Здесь я привязываю замыкание к текущему экземпляру и указываю новую область видимости - класс `TestGrandPa`:

```
$binded = $closure->bindTo($this, 'TestGrandPa');
```

Если бы я описал метод просто:

```
public function prepare()
{
//        $closure = function() {
//            return $this->_models;
//        };
//        $binded = $closure->bindTo($this, 'TestGrandPa');
    $this->setModels($this->prepareGreet($this->_models));
}
```

На выходе получил бы `Hello !`.

Т.е. для Вашего случая, чтобы достучаться до `BaseDataProvider::$_models`, нужно переписать метод так:

```
public function prepare($forcePrepare = false)
{
    parent::prepare($forcePrepare);

    if ($forcePrepare || $this->_tree === null) {
        $closure = function() { return $this->_models; };
        $binded = $closure->bindTo($this, 'yii\data\BaseDataProvider');
        $this->_tree = $this->prepareTree($binded());
    }
}
```

*Еще раз замечу, что предпочтительнее (проще поддерживать потом будет) пересмотреть ряд архитектурных решений, которые привели к возникновению этой проблемы.*